# How to setup to get smtp log from rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Can someone tell me how to configure rails to get an smtp log.

thanks,
ash

Answer (score 0):

There is no special methods in Ruby to deal with SMTP logs, I suppose, so:

```
log = `tail /path/to/your/smtp/logs -n 100`.split(/[\r\n]+/)
```